# Error on Quotations on every line using variables

Tags: python, string

I am attempting to get a header to print the whole wall of text at once, and I need variable to be displayed along with the wall. I have defined all variables and used .format to get them to be in the string. I get a syntax error on every quotation besides the first line. I am using Idle if that makes any difference

I've tried to put the variable outside of the string and separate with a comma and it still gives the same error

```
print("# Activity {0} Task {1}".format(activity, task)
"# File:  {0}".format(file)
"# Date:    {0}".format(date)
"# By:       {0}".format(name)
"# Section: {0}".format(section)
"# Team:    {0}".format(team)
"# "
"# ELECTRONIC SIGNATURE"
"# {0}".format(name)
"# "
"# The electronic signature above indicates the script"
"# submitted for evaluation is my individual work, and I"
"# have a general understanding of all aspects of its"
"# development and execution."
"# "
"# {0}".format(desciption)
```

It gives a syntax error on the last quotation on the second line.

Comment: You need commas between all the arguments to `print()`

Comment: You're also missing the final `)` around all the arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar, it printed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running python 3.6+ then you can use the **f-prefix** instead to concatenate values directly in strings. It's much simpler and cleaner. More info [here](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/).

Example:

```py
activity, task, file, date, name = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' 

result = f'''# Activity {activity} Task {task}
# File: {file}
# Date: {date}
# By:   {name}'''

print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
# Activity a Task b
# File: c
# Date: d
# By:   e
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just format them all together in a multi-line string - using `'''`.

E.g.

```
print('''Hello this is five: {} and
Now on this second line I sub in six: {}.
We are approaching the {} of this example.
Goodbye.'''.format(5, 6, 'end'))
```

Which works. Giving:

```
Hello this is five: 5 and
Now on this second line I sub in six: 6.
We are approaching the end of this example.
Goodbye.
```

Or you could just use multiple print statements:

```
print("# Activity {0} Task {1}".format(activity, task))
print("# File:  {0}".format(file))
print("# Date:    {0}".format(date))
print("# By:       {0}".format(name))
```

This second way may be more maintainable as lines can easily be re-shuffled and it is clear where each variable is substituted. However I think it looks more ugly as more characters are wasted.